# How to cite future conference poster session on CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, citations, cv, presentation, psychology

How would you go about listing a conference/symposium poster presentation that will happen in the future on your CV if the title or abstract haven't been decided yet?

For instance, the future conference/symposium for my case is university run so it is certain that the proposal submission will get approved for presenting. However, I have not yet collected all the data so I do not have an abstract or title prepared.

I have seen some people put,

Last name, first initial. (year, estimated month). *Title of presentation*. Poster session presented at [location]. (Planned)

I thought about preparing a tentative title since I know the general topic, but wanted more opinions or answers from those that had a better idea about this.

I've looked around a bit on the internet and found some information on this topic but it was primarily on invited talks rather than planned presentations.
Thank you in advance to those who answer!

*This is for the CV I will be turning in as supplemental material for Psychology PhD application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a future event so tenuous, I would recommend against putting it in your CV at all.

Even if you think your CV is thin, it will not be improved by putting in an abstract that might or might not get presented and that you haven't even started to prepare.