# Is it acceptable to put a future event in one's CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

I'm working on my CV for graduate school applications and was wondering about my "Presentation" section. I know that I will be attending the American Chemical Society Conference in Spring 2017 (they accepted my abstract), so is it acceptable to list that as one of my presentations?

Comment: I know there's a similar topic here (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/76935/how-to-cite-future-conference-poster-session-on-cv), but I do have an abstract submitted and accepted.

Comment: If the paper has been accepted and scheduled, you can list it.  It's a bit of CV stuffing but relatively minor in the scheme of things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, but to avoid confusion, clearly label it as such.

Similar to how you can list papers with *(submitted)* or *(under review)*, you can list presentations and posters as *(confirmed)* or some other indication that the plan is final and has been accepted.  If you don't label it as such, there is a risk the reader may believe the year is erroneous.